# android imageview display in bad quality

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, appearance

I try to display 3 images medium size.
The problem is that they display in low quality and it damages the UI a lot,I checked over the internet and the best solution is to use is Piccaso,but I want to know how can I display the image in it's full quality without third-library?
I load images like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnring"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/itayring1"

        />
```

and I also tried this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.itayicon);
    b1.setImageBitmap(bb);
```

When I used Eclipse I could load images easly. There must be a way to do in Android Studio too,
Thanks.

Comment: You can use directly imageview.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawble);

Comment: b1 is ImageView defined in the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Put Images in xhdpi drawable image only and try this code :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnring"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/itayring1"
    />
```